# Isometric Map Rendering Incorrectly

Tags: xna, c#, isometric

I've currently been trying my hand at Isometric map rendering via the tutorial over at XNA resources; http://www.xnaresources.com/default.asp?page=Tutorial:TileEngineSeries:4

However, unfortuanely the map isn't quite rendering as you can see in this photo of my output; https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Gelo.png

I've not too sure where i'm going wrong, here below is my rendering code;

```
        protected override void Draw (GameTime gameTime)

    {

        graphics.GraphicsDevice.Clear (Color.CornflowerBlue);



        //Set Up Screen Geo, see how many times we can display on the screen

        int tileOnX = ((int)scroll.X / tileWidth);

        int tileOnScreenX = (((tileOnX * tileWidth) + graphics.PreferredBackBufferWidth) / stepX) + 1;

        int tileOnY = ((int)scroll.Y / tileHeight);

        int tileOnScreenY = (((tileOnY * tileHeight) + graphics.PreferredBackBufferHeight) / stepY) + 1;



        if (tileOnScreenX > isoMap.getWidth())

            tileOnScreenX = isoMap.getWidth();



        if (tileOnScreenY > isoMap.getHeight ())

            tileOnScreenY = isoMap.getHeight ();



        //Set up Depth 

        float maxdepth = ((isoMap.getWidth() + 1) * ((isoMap.getHeight() + 1) * tileWidth)) / 10;

        //Locals

        int tileX, tileY;

        float depthOffset;



        spriteBatch.Begin (SpriteSortMode.BackToFront, BlendState.AlphaBlend);



        //Draw Iso Map

        for (int y = tileOnY; y < tileOnScreenY; y++)

        {

            int rowOffset = 0;

            if ((tileOnY + y) % 2 == 1)

                rowOffset = oddRowXOffset;



            for (int x = tileOnX; x < tileOnScreenX; x++)

            {

                //Draw Base Layer Cells

                foreach (int tileID in isoMap.rows[y].columns[x].getBaseCells()) {

                    //Get Current Tile

                    tileX = (tileID % numberOfTilesPerRow) * tileWidth;

                    tileY = (tileID / numberOfTilesPerRow) * tileHeight;



                    //Set Poisition Rect

                    basePosition.X = (x * stepX) - (int)scroll.X + rowOffset;

                    basePosition.Y = (y * stepY) - (int)scroll.Y + baseOffsetY;

                    basePosition.Width = tileWidth;

                    basePosition.Height = tileHeight;

                    //Set Source Rectangle 

                    baseImagePoisition.X = tileX;

                    baseImagePoisition.Y = tileY;

                    baseImagePoisition.Width = tileWidth;

                    baseImagePoisition.Height = tileHeight;



                    spriteBatch.Draw (tileSheet, basePosition, baseImagePoisition, Color.White, 0.0f, Vector2.Zero, SpriteEffects.None, 1.0f);

                }



                //Draw Core Layer Cells

                int heightRow = 0;

                depthOffset = 0.7f - ((tileOnX + (tileOnY * tileWidth)) / maxdepth);

                foreach (int tileID in isoMap.rows[y].columns[x].getCoreCells())

                {

                    //Get Current Tile

                    tileX = (tileID % numberOfTilesPerRow) * tileWidth;

                    tileY = (tileID / numberOfTilesPerRow) * tileHeight;



                    //Set Poisition Rect

                    corePosition.X = (x * stepX) - (int)scroll.X + rowOffset;

                    corePosition.Y = (y * stepY) - (int)scroll.Y + baseOffsetY - (heightRow * 32);

                    corePosition.Width = tileWidth;

                    corePosition.Height = tileHeight;

                    //Set Source Rectangle 

                    coreImagePoisition.X = tileX;

                    coreImagePoisition.Y = tileY;

                    coreImagePoisition.Width = tileWidth;

                    coreImagePoisition.Height = tileHeight;



                    spriteBatch.Draw (tileSheet, corePosition, coreImagePoisition, Color.White, 0.0f, Vector2.Zero, SpriteEffects.None, 

                                      depthOffset - ((float)heightRow * heightRowDepthMod));

                    heightRow++;

                }





            }

        }



        spriteBatch.End ();

        base.Draw (gameTime);

    }

}
```

Any help with this would be greatly appreciated. P.s - The base layer of tiles is rendering correctly just in case anyone was wondering, i just kept the entire base layer at tileID 0. *the plain grass tile you see in my output :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
int mapx = (tileOnX + x);
int mapy = (tileOnY + y);
depthOffset = 0.7f - ((mapx + (mapy * tileWidth)) / maxdepth);
```

I forgot to add on the incrementing x & y values from the for-loop :/.